# sending text from editText to ListView (2 activities)

Tags: java, android

i am new to Andriod and programming. i am trying to make a to do list app, which will contain a listView, Button(add) in the main layout. when i click add i want it to go to another activity which will contain a editText and a add button. when i click the add button i want to update the list in my main activity. Now i was able to get the information from the second activity but when i try to add it in my list it over writes it.

How can i update my list as soon as my main activity appears again.

Here's what i have so far :

MainActivity class :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
    addItems(); // i think this is the error but i dont know how to fix it.
    alList = new ArrayList<String>();
    aaList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alList);
    list.setAdapter(aaList);

}
public void clickAdd(View v) { //when clicking the add button(add)
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItem.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void addItems(){
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("item");
    aaList.add(s);
    aaList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

AddItem class :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_layout);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdd);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);

}
public void add(View v){ //when clicking the add button(bt) 
    edit = et.getText().toString(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddItem.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("item", edit);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Can you please tell me where and why i am going wrong? Thank You

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should use `startACtivityForResult`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Then in your second Activity

```
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```

And back in your fist one:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {

     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
         String result=data.getStringExtra("result");          
     }
     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
     }
  }
}//onActivityResult
```

and then, your addItem should do the trick:

```
private void addItems(String s){
    aaList.add(s);
    aaList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it works fine, but when i rotate my phone the list disappears, is this because when you change the orientation, the onCreate() is called again and so a new array adapter is created?

Comment: Yes, indeed, you should save your notes in a database, it will allow easy sorting, filtering, modification, add//delete.. But that's an other topic!